# How to solve the ordinary differential Equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\mathrm{d} x_1}{\mathrm{d} t} & =-x_1+x_2\\
\frac{\mathrm{d} x_2}{\mathrm{d} t} & =x_1\cos t -x_2
\end{aligned}
\label{eq:3.6}
\end{equation}

At the beginning, I prove the zero solution is stable, then I used Maltab ode45 function test more than 10 different initial points, they all convergenced to zero, so I guess the zero solution asymptotically stable, But I can't prove it. So I want to know how to solve the ODEs.

Comment: $x_2=x_1+\frac{dx_1}{dt}$ . Put it into the second equation leading to a linear second order ODE. The solution involves special functions MathieuS and MathieuC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a complete answer to the question.
$$(x_1e^t)'=x_2e^t$$
$$(x_2e^t)'=(x_1e^t)\cos t$$
Then substitute $u=x_1e^t$ and $v=x_2e^t$:
$$u'=v$$
$$v'=u\cos t$$
Now we need to solve the differential equation :
$$u''-u\cos t=0$$
This is [Mathieu's differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathieu_function) and there are no solution with elementary functions.
$$y''(x)+(a-2q \cos (2x))y(x)=0$$

Comment: Thanks !!!!!!!!!

Comment: You're welcome @Nichts__97